# Downgrading 9.0.83 Google Play Services manually

Tags: google-play-services

I got the following log error in my route tracking activity

> 06-24 18:50:24.488 7128-7759/com.noureddine_ouertani.www.wocelli50
>   E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find
>   class
>   "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates.ModuleDescriptor"
>   on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.noureddine_ouertani.www.wocelli50-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64,
>   /system/lib64]]

After reading some posts and answers  about this log error I figured out that it's a known Google Play Services version  9.0.83 issue that causes bugs in some apps that use a GoogleApiClient like mine.

However I didn't test the solution yet. I wanted to downgrade Google Play Services on my Smartphone but Uninstall Updates was greyed out (see Screenshot).

[image: screenshot]

Does anyone know how to do this manually?

I installed the Android Device Manager app but found no possibility to influence the stop/uninstall updates buttons of Google Play Services. Then I tried to apply [this solution](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/help/delete-disable-downgrade-prevent-update-t3091832) but the System App Remover app got no root permission on my Smartphone.

Any hints or help?

Comment: *Then I tried to apply this solution but the System App Remover app got no root permission on my Smartphone*, like i said in my answer at that chatroom, Did you check if your device is root or not? with an app such as; https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joeykrim.rootcheck ?

Comment: Apart from that: "this issue", "this solution" – references are a good thing. But don't expect people following a couple of links *to understand your problem* (most won't), better include the essentials so readers have a chance to get an idea without having to follow the link (but can do so for additional details).

Comment: +1 for the Izzy comment. I did not track the links to understand your problem or incorporate what you believed was a remediation of it. Please edit all information into your posting.

Comment: Post edited. thanks for your comments. PS: I''m rooting my device right now and will post here whether I solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem for my Huawei P8 Lite Android phone like this:

1. I unlocked my bootloader
2. I rooted my phone
3. I succesfully checked with [Root Checker Basic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joeykrim.rootcheck) that my phone is rooted
4. I downloaded and installed System App Remover from the Google Play Store.
5. I put my device in Airplane Mode in order to prevent auto upgrade of GPS.
6. I opened System App Remover and select "System App" from the menu.
7. After I found Google Play Services in the list which was marked as "Should keep" I selected it and pressed "Uninstall". I ignored the next warning.
8. Using Settings/Apps, I saw that Google Play Services "Uninstall Updates", and "Disable" Buttons were no longer be grayed out.
9. I pressed "Uninstall Updates"

Here is the result: Downgrade of Google Play Services to 8.1.18

[image]

Comment: This reprieve may be temporary. I don't believe you can prevent the automatic upgrade, either intentionally or as its byproduct of other Google app(s) updates. You'll probably encounter this again, unless it is/was isolated to the specific version you had encountered the problem. With luck later versions will eradicate the bug, and the problems it caused.